# Email notifications lead creation via REST API and run through assignment rules

Tags: rest-api, email, leads, assignment-rules, lead-assignment

When creating leads via the REST API, the email notifications that are configured in the lead assigment rules don't get triggered, the lead assigment rules DO run.

According to this help page, when using the SOAP API you have to set specific headers for the email notifications to be send, it also specifies this is NOT the case for the REST API, but it also does not describe if it is possible.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323134&type=1

When creating leads via the REST API that get assigned through the assignment rules, and I want the notification email send, do I have to manually automate an email send with another api call to the email endpoint or a basic flow?

When switching owners or creating new leads in SF UI the email notification configured in the lead assigment rules gets send as expected.

Comment: you could disable the header in the REST call and then do a future/queueable on Lead create that ran assignment rules w/ email notification

Comment: Thanks cropredy! Found it in this case easier to display all notifications with the assigment rules and build a flow. Had to re-create the notification this way as well.